# Is it possible to make a Captive Portal from the windows Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wifi, captiveportal

I was wandering if the **Wi-Fi** of the **computers Hotspot** can be turned into a **Captive Portal**. I want to create a Wi-Fi hotspot from the Computer and when someone connects to the Wi-Fi it should redirect to a specific webpage on the LAN on opening their browser. I am using XAMPP server to host all my files.
I can connect to the page but I need to type the IP Address every time from all devices I connect. Usually this feature is given on some routers but I want to find out if it possible using Computer as Wi-Fi Hotspot.

**I know there are some software's which can do this on windows, but I want to know if it is possible using windows commands/BAT/VBS/PowerShell!**

Comment: What you are searching for is manipulating DHCP data of your windows 'hotspot' for using a DNS server which you have to install on your (let's call it) router, which redirects to this page. Or a nice transparent reverse proxy. But coding this with a vbs or batch file isn't that easy. PowerShell **could** do that but you don't want it to do it...

Comment: Ok! You can add your solution in PowerShell code also explain how to use it.

Comment: can you tell me the windows software that make this possible?